# jQuery in Firefox - event is undefined why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with jQuery inside Firefox.. i don't know why i am getting an undefined e (event) error. In Chrome and IE and Safari works just fine.

it keep saying undefined event.. what am i doing wrong here?

Thanks!

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function handleVideoModal() {
        $('.js-trigger-video-modal').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var id = $(this).attr('data-youtube-id');
            var autoplay = '?autoplay=1';
            var related_no = '&rel=0';
            var src = '//www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + autoplay + related_no;

            $('#youtube').attr('src', src);
            $('body').addClass('show-video-modal noscroll');
        });

        function handleCloseModal() {
            event.preventDefault();

            $('body').removeClass('show-video-modal noscroll');

            $('#youtube').attr('src', '');
        }

        $('body').on(
            'click',
            '.close-video-modal, .video-modal .overlay',
            function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                handleCloseModal();
            }
        );

        $('body').keyup(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                handleCloseModal();
            }
        });
    }
    handleVideoModal();
});
```

Comment: because you do not pass event to the method. Some browsers have a global event. too lazy to find the dupe.

Comment: You set up the first "click" handler correctly, but `handleCloseModal()` expects `event` to be defined. Declare that function with an `event` parameter and pass `event` in from the body "click" handler.

Comment: You aren't being consistent with the event prevention for the 2 instances you call `handleCloseModal()` either. Make up your mind if you want to prevent before calling it or doing it inside that function. In one instance you prevent already before calling it

Comment: Note: FF supports the global `event` monstruosity since a few versions already. You may want to update your browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a probleme in your code's logic. This is a cross browser compatibility issue.

Try using `window.event` instead.

More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event).

Comment: `window.event` is proprietary and not supported by Firefox.